# How to insert only mac address from regular log in rsyslog?

Tags: mysql, regex, rsyslog

Hi how to insert only mac address like this '22:22:22:22:22:22' from regular log?

My rsyslog template:

```
$template fw,"insert into fw(Message, Facility, FromHost, Priority, DeviceReportedTime, ReceivedAt, InfoUnitID, SysLogTag, EventID) values ('%msg%', %syslogfacility%,'%fromhost%', %syslogpriority%, '%timereported:::date-mysql%', '%timegenerated:::date-mysql%', %iut%, '%syslogtag%', '123')",SQL
```

I try with regex like this but I get string only "src-mac" in mysql table

```
%msg:R,ERE,0,FIELD:src-mac--end%
```

log text msg is like this :

```
Pay: srcnat: in:(none) out:wan, src-mac 22:22:22:22:22:22, 
proto TCP (SYN), 10.5.50.100:1111->111.11.111.11:443, len 52
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard policy for ingesting data is to "cleanse" it in some application language before doing the INSERTs.

Unless you have MariaDB with regexp_replace(), there is no easy way in SQL to pick out the mac address.